# CSS animation ignores z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations

I want to have two images overlapping eachother with the animated image at the back and the static image overlapping.  Without the animation it works fine with the red overlapping the black image.

As soon as I add the css animation it ignores the z-index set and the black overlaps the red.  How do I bring the red image to the front?

**I have a working solution using css backgrounds but I want the images to be responsive**

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7992/

css here

```
.rotate{
z-index: 1;
-webkit-animation:rotation 20s linear infinite;
-o-animation:rotation 20s infinite linear;
-moz-animation:rotation 20s infinite linear;
animation:rotation 20s infinite linear;overflow:visible;}
@keyframes  rotation{0%{}100%{transform:rotate(-360deg);}}@-moz-keyframes  rotation
{
0%   {}
100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}}
@-webkit-keyframes  rotation 
{
0%   {}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes  rotation
{
0%   {}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

.static {
    z-index:10;
    margin-top: -232px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z-index` doesn't work on non-positioned elements.

I've added `position: relative;` and all is well: http://jsfiddle.net/q9vsqpyw/

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` works only on positioned elements. That means `relative`, `absolute` and `fixed`. Does not work on `static` elements. By default, elements have `position: static;`.

Change it to `position: relative;` and it will work.